# "what their journey is all about" meaning?

Tags: expressions

Today I read famous quote by Regina Brett.

> Don't compare your life to others'. You have no idea what their journey is all about.

From here I can' make out meaning of the phrase "what their journey is all about".

would you explain to me in other easy sentence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writers sometimes use the word "journey" as a poetic way of saying "life, and all the things that happened".

So "Don't compare your life to others'. You have no idea what their life has been like and what has happened to them during their life."

Answer (score 1):

The idiom [*is all about*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_all_about) is used to introduce what is considered the focus, or most important part, of something.

In your example, the word journey is a metaphor for life; i.e., the journey of life.

You could reword the sentence as “*You have no idea what are the main things that happened in their life*”.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the following definition:

> **Journey** *noun*
>   1.1 A long and often difficult process of personal change and development.
>   *‘her spiritual journey towards Roman Catholicism’*,
>   *‘Now, though, she would begin a new journey, a new life, if one as old as she could ask for such a thing.’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/journey)

I read your quote as advising against saying things like "Oh, he's got such an easy life compared to mine." The second sentence in the quote asserts that comparing your life to another's in this way isn't advisable because you don't know the things that they have gone through.